# Extracting list of names and underlying hyperlinks from webpage using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to web-scraping and trying to get a handle on using `rvest` to collect data from a webpage. The webpage of interest is https://www.cabq.gov/office-of-neighborhood-coordination/neighborhood-homeowner-coalition-websites, which provides a list of community organizations with underlying hyperlinks to the organizations' websites. I am trying to produce a data frame in which the first column is the organization name and the second column is the URL from the hyperlink.

I've followed a couple of `rvest` tutorials and Stack Overflow questions to try to parse out the appropriate nodes to extract the information I'm interested in to no avail. The desired output would look like this (the `...` is just truncating the output in the middle between the desired beginning and end of the output table goal):

```
| organization                                   | URL                                 |
| ---------------------------------------------- | ----------------------------------- |
| 7 Bar North Homeowners Association             | https://www.7barnorthhoa.com/       |
| Academy Acres North Neighborhood Association   | http://www.aanna.org/               |
....
| Willow Wood Neighborhood Association           | http://www.hoamcoweb.com/willowwood |
| Winrock Villas Condominium Association         | http://winrockvillas.hoaspace.com/  |
```

My code attempt is below.

```r
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

URL <- "https://www.cabq.gov/office-of-neighborhood-coordination/neighborhood-homeowner-coalition-websites"

pg <- read_html(URL)

html_nodes(pg, "external-link") %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    data_frame(
      postal = html_node(x, "span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE),
      city = html_nodes(x, "ul > li") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
    )
  })  
#> # A tibble: 0 x 0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you need to use an [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) expression to get the correct type of links. You are interested in **a** elements of class *external-link*, so you can use:

```
html_nodes(pg, xpath="//a[@class='external-link']")
```

You can build a more complex xpath expression that suits what you need to get. Then you need to extract the text and one attribute of the element, you can use:

```
html_nodes(pg, xpath="//a[@data-linktype='external' or 
 @class='external-link']") %>% 
map_df(function(x) {
data_frame(
  organization =  x %>% html_text(trim=TRUE),
  URL = x %>% html_attr("href")
)})
```

Comment: This seems close (thanks!) but does not yield all of the organizations listed. It appears that only some are under the `external-link` class, but others are under things like `a data-val=`.

Comment: Yes, that true, you use xpath to search more complex patterns: html_nodes(pg, xpath="//a[@data-linktype='external' or @class='external-link']")

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you, José! Just so I'm getting the syntax here (as I'm new to using xpaths), this is saying: "for all <a> tags that contain @data-linktype='external' or <a> tags that contain class='external-link' pass the text to the organization variable and the URL in the underlying <a href> tag to the URL variable"? Something I'm still not quite clear on is the function of the brackets in the `html_nodes()` command

Comment: Hi Abe, in xpath `//a` will search all `<a>` tags, the brackets `[...]` are used for subsetting or filtering, the `@` is used to refers to an attribute within the tag. 
The xpath expression: `//a[@data-linktype='external' or @class='external-link']` 
would read: "select all *<a>* tags that have attribute *data-linktype* with value  'external' or attribute *class* with value 'external-link'